# SQL: Variable to update a set of items

Tags: sql, database, get, set, where-clause

SO, each item has an id, a setId, and a name.

Current data may only have one NAME field filled out in an entire set.

EX>

```
>ID = 1 >NAME = 'Bob' >SETID = 5
>ID = 2 >NAME = NULL  >SETID = 5
>ID = 3 >NAME = NULL  >SETID = 5
>ID = 4 >NAME = NULL  >SETID = 5
```

I am looking for an SQL script that GET the one record that is not null in a "SET"
SET the remaining items in the "SET" for that "NAME" record.

The end result I am aiming for would look like this:

```
>ID = 1 >NAME = 'Bob' >SETID = 5
>ID = 2 >NAME = 'Bob' >SETID = 5
>ID = 3 >NAME = 'Bob' >SETID = 5
>ID = 4 >NAME = 'Bob' >SETID = 5
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Will that affect the code, bcuz I don't have that

Comment: Yes, it will and yes, you do have it. It's the database you're using, something like `SQL Server`, `MySQL`, `Oracle`...?

Comment: SQL server, pardon me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is only one `Name` in a set that is not null, you could use a `CTE` and do something like:

```
;WITH NameHelper AS 
(
    SELECT
        Name,
        SetID
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Name, SetID
)

UPDATE MyTable SET Name = NameHelper.Name
FROM MyTable
    INNER JOIN NameHelper ON MyTable.SetID = NameHelper.SetID
```

Comment: I would, but apparently 15 rep is required for that.